# Which controller is setting a flash message?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Is there a way- besides looking over all my code- to find out what controller is setting a flash message?

I have this message that is displaying on all pages, except `admin_` pages, which I apparently set at some point during testing, but I would like to get rid of.

I have searched through much of my code for `$this->Session->setFlash` but I can't seem to find where the problem is.

Comment: how about searching for the message that is displayed? Using Netbeans or Eclipse, you can search your whole project easily

Comment: Yeah.. I did that tonight and I was able to find it in a controller, I had manually gone over before. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no. Technically the flash message can be set from anywhere as it's just a session value. Instead, you can debug the location right above the flash message.

In your view, add the debug statement under where the flash message is set.

```
echo $this->Session->flash();
debug($this->here);
```

Comment: Yeah... this only shows me the current location. It does not tell me what controller is setting this up... I will keep on digging thru mu code

Comment: Like I said, you can't tell what specific controller is setting it. The action it was currently on is what set it last, so use the debug statement to track your actions. It's set by an action (usually), then showing the message removes it from the session. So, logically, the previous action set the current flash message.

Comment: I searched thru all my code to find it as nothing else worked. However, I appreciate your suggestion....